# Using JS for page template causing slow loading

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

In my blog (hosted by Blogger) I have kind of a gallery page.

For every new entry I added to that page I was copy-paste last entry and modify it with the new content. The result was a very long page with code repetition and quite monkey work by me.

This is how it looks:

```
<div style="justify-content: space-around; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <a href="https://example.com/article1.html">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://example.com/article1.jpeg" />
    </a>  
    <div style="padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; text-align: center;">
      <a href="https://example.com/article1.html" style="text-decoration: none;">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <a href="https://example.com/article2.html">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://example.com/article2.jpeg" />
    </a>  
    <div style="padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; text-align: center;">
      <a href="https://example.com/article2.html" style="text-decoration: none;">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <a href="https://example.com/article3.html">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://example.com/article3.jpeg" />
    </a>  
    <div style="padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; text-align: center;">
      <a href="https://example.com/article3.html" style="text-decoration: none;">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yesterday after adding a few more entries I decided to look for a shorter method and I ended up using JS like this:

```
<div>
  <div id="articlesMain" style="justify-content: space-around; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  articles = [
    {
      image: 'https://example.com/article1.jpeg',
      link: 'https://example.com/article1.html'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://example.com/article2.jpeg',
      link: 'https://example.com/article2.html'
    },
    {
      image: 'https://example.com/article3.jpeg',
      link: 'https://example.com/article3.html'
    },
  ]

  for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    var article = document.createElement("div");
    article.innerHTML = `
      <div style="align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <a href="${articles[i].link}">
          <img class="lazyload" data-src="${articles[i].image}" />
        </a>  
        <div style="padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; text-align: center;">
          <a href="${articles[i].link}" style="text-decoration: none;">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    
    articleMain.appendChild(article);
  }
</script>
```

This piece of code does exactly what I intended it to do, saves me time and keeps my code quite small.

However, it cause to a weird behavior when I check its performance using PageSpeed Insights - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Instead of a score, I am getting this short sentence: `Lighthouse returned error: Something went wrong.`

After reading a bit of reasons for this error I found some claims that page load time or lack of elements on the page might cause this to happen. Although I must say that in my human eyes I didn't notice any slow page load...

So my question is how can I change my JS code to gain back my wonderful score?

Thanks

---

Update: I tried @evolutionxbox suggestion:

```
...
var article = document.createElement("div");
article.innerHTML = ``

for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    article.innerHTML += `
        ...
    `
}

articlesMain.appendChild(article);
```

But I am still getting that error. For sanity check I used my old code without the JS loop and the page speed test works perfect.

---

Update 2:

This time I tried @Heretic Monkey suggestion to use `DocumentFragment` and this is what I ended up with:

```
...
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
  var articleHTML= document.createElement("div");
  articleHTML.innerHTML = `
        ...
    `
  fragment.appendChild(articleHTML);
})

articlesMain.appendChild(fragment);
```

Yet again I am getting the same error.

Maybe this is not a legit approach to my issue?
Is there any other method I should try in order to gain a template-like ability without the use JS like that?

Comment: Append outside the loop.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Only the last article will be added then. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained a little more. Create a string before the loop. In each loop, concatenate the article HTML string with that initial string. After the loop, set the inner html of the div and append it to the article main.

Comment: Or use a document fragment and append that after the loop. Basically, whenever you update `innerHTML` in a loop like that, the browser has to rerender the whole page to figure out where things should lie, on every iteration. If you update `innerHTML` once, that rerender happens once.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I update the question with your suggestion - still getting the error.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you write an example please? I am not familiar with document fragment.

Comment: I'm busy. Do some searching on the internet. There are many, many examples.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done, with no luck either... (see post update #2)

Comment: What lazy loading library are you using? Why are you using inline styles rather than classes? Are you **sure** you are targeting the `#articlesMain` as you don't include that within your code example (`articleMain.append` doesn't have `articleMain` defined.)? How many items are on the actual page?  Are you getting any console errors when you load the page? How big are the images you are trying to lazy load? A best guess is that the lazy load library is failing due to adding items one by one and items shifting breaking any `intersectionObservers` but your example doesn't show that.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks for replying. In my second code block (there are 4 in total as for now) row #2 defines `#articlesMain` I felt it is not necessary to include it in my updates as well. For lazy loading I am using `lazysizes - v5.2.2`. No console errors. In the page I am testing this code on there are 8 elements. Images average size is 100KB. As for your guess, without the JS loop code (just pure HTML like in my first code block), including the lazyload classes - everything works. I actually thought, like you at first, and removed the lazyload from that page - still getting that error.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest as this seems hard to replicate is to share the URL and I will see if anything jumps out, it can sometimes be something completely unrelated.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I created 2 pages (one with each method) which can be found here https://pastebin.com/TXi0jja9

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Man! Thanks to you I realized that in the "old" page there a `<br />` tag just before `articlesMain` div. When I added it to the "new" page - it solved the problem! the score is 3-5 points lower but it is kind of expected since I am using JS.

Comment: Yeah it will be slower if you put the JS in an external file. If you can inline the JS on the page that would be quicker so maybe give that a go as the execution time and size of such a simple JS script is negligible the reason it is slower will be because you have to wait for a network request. Glad you got it sorted bud, good luck with the site.

Comment: Thank you! The JS is inline and yet there is a slight hit in the score comparing to HTML alone. By the way, do you have any idea why that `<br/>` tag cause that issue?